# Android listview prevent sideways (left-right) swiping when scrolling

Tags: android, listview, scroll, gesture

I'm using this library https://github.com/romannurik/android-swipetodismiss to implement swipe to delete in my listview. However the problem is that when my fling or up-down swipe is too slanted, it turns into a sideway swipe to remove row gesture and then the listview stops scrolling. I think the ideal behavior should be if the gesture is a up-down scrolling gesture, then the x component of the gesture should be ignored and vice versa for the sideways swipe to delete gesture. Is there a way to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: AFAIK it isn't a library, just some sample code for people to implement. With that said, your problem is taken care of within the sample with the `SwipeDismissListViewTouchListener` and `SwipeDismissListViewTouchListener.makeScrollListener()`

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the ideal behavior is the default behavior of the library. The problem was I set my own onScrollListener which I think overrode the library's listener.

Comment: Oops...didn't see this when I posted my comment, but either way, glad you found a solution.